# Can I detect javascript codes that working from bookmarks?

Tags: javascript, php, external

We can use javascript codes as bookmarks on some web browsers. For example;

```
javascript: document.getElementById("username").value = bybrown;
```

If we add this as an bookmark to Opera and we will click it on a loaded page with a input named "username", it will fill it.

Lets assume that a logged user is doing this on a PHP script. I am wondering , is there any way to detect it and saving the user?

Comment: via AJAX yes, browser detects element change via JS, makes ajax call to php script on server. Cant see any real world use for this.

Comment: What do you mean "doing this on a PHP script"? After page is loaded, it's just a page, no PHP there.

Comment: Yes you can detect it, but just curious, why do you want to know that? Any validation should be done by PHP, and not by Javascript (PHP = server side and Javascript = client side) - also PHP can't be changed by using a 'javascript-bookmark'

Comment: What do you mean by "sand saving the user"?

Comment: Yeah, just add a input event listener function, and do whatever in there, but don't assume that will work for everyone as lots of pepz have js turned off!

Comment: php was just an example. sorry for my bad explanation. i mean, i am using a php system and users filling required inputs automatically and i dont want this. i want to see and save to my database these users for blocking.

Comment: @cemekkazan "and I don't want this" - well, bad news. It's their browser and you have little to no control there.